# How to deal with Enchantments outside of G/W?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have done gatherer searches for "destroy" and "exile" target enchantment with White and Green excluded. Are there any options, save counterspells, for dealing with them?

Comment: Related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4858/how-do-i-deal-with-enchantments-while-playing-mono-red?rq=1

Comment: Can you post a link to the Gatherer search that you performed?

Comment: http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%7C%5BDestroy%5D%7C%5BExile%5D+%5BTarget%5D+%5Benchantment%5D&color=+!%5BG%5D+!%5BW%5D

Comment: Nevinyrral's Disk.

Comment: Are you against G/W specifically or not-Green and not-White as well?  Green alone has good enchant removal and Green mixed with almost all other colors does too.

Comment: @EthanTheBrave Based on the search link they provided, they're looking for enchant removal outside of either G or W, not outside of a G/W deck. So, anything in U, R, B or colourless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Enchantments are permanents, so they can also be destroyed by spells or abilities that destroy permanents**

There are several non-G/W cards that destroy certain types of permanents, rather than enchantments specifically: [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[permanent]+[destroy]&color=+![G]+![W])

You can also make your opponent sacrifice certain types of permanents, although that of course leaves some degree of choice for your opponent, depending on the board state: [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[sacrifices]+[permanent]&color=+![G]+![W])

Generally, you should accept the fact that enchantment destruction is firmly inside the G/W part of the color pie, and you should look to less direct ways of dealing with enchantments.

As for direct answers, your best bet outside G/W are Blue counterspells and bounce effects for tempo, and sweeper artifacts.